# AudioFileStreamParseBytes failed to call my audio callback

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, audio-streaming

AudioFileStreamOpen set up my audio callback and AudioFileStreamParseBytes has parsed the data (I believe they both succeed b/c the return value is 0).

But by audio callback was not got called. Any reason ?

Update: I think that may be because AudioFileStreamParseBytes is parsing id3 tags. Now the difficulty I am facing is that if I have songs with different bit rates and sample rates, I don't know how I can let AudioFileStreamParseBytes handle them correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: What file format is the audio? Are you getting anything on the property callback?